Can I guarantee a block of an attack with Peerless Aim by attacking their weapon (in this case a hand/claw) with my shield?
Peerless Aim reads:

Peerless Aim. When you miss with an attack roll, you can hit instead. Once you use this benefit, you can’t use it again until the start of your next turn.

If an opponent is attacking me with claws, can I make an attack roll on their claws, using peerless aim to guarantee that I hit, thus blocking their attack? I'm expecting to fight an opponent that I can't afford to take a hit from, so I need to find ways to block it. I'm a level 20 cleric, but in this scenario I can't use spells.

No.
You can't interrupt the opponent's attack with an attack of your own. You have to wait until your own turn to attack.
You can Ready an action to respond to an attack by making an attack; e.g. "If an enemy attacks me, I attack his claws." However, that would still not stop his attack, it would just hit him normal. There's no regular action which allows you to roll an attack to counteract an opponent's attacks.
Also, the rules on Readying are that the triggering action finishes first. You would have to Ready an action for an earlier step, like "If he approaches within 5 feet of me." Now, you would be safe if that action was one which rendered him unable to attack, such as applying a status like Paralyzed or Dead. However, in general, you can't roll an attack to block his attack. That's not a standard D&D rule.
For a level 20 cleric, may I recommend Divine Intervention? Perhaps ask your deity for your spells back.

Divine Intervention is a good option to consider, but unfortunately it's going to still be on cooldown when the fight starts. Maybe I could draw the fight out until it's not, but I used it a little under 5 days ago to appoint someone as a cleric, after I taught them cantrip-9th level spells. By the time the fight starts, the cooldown will have 2-3 hours remaining.
